# Eiffel - How can I initialize a LINKED_LIST?

Tags: linked-list, eiffel

I'm new to Eiffel and I'm trying to create an instance of Linked_List. I'm not really sure of how to do this with this class because I receive an syntax error whenever I try to do it that way. This is what I have:

```
class
    APPLICATION

inherit
    ARGUMENTS

create
    make

feature {NONE} -- Initialization

    make
        --  
        local
            lista:LINKED_LIST[MONOMIO]

        do
        lista.make
    end
end
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
Error code: VUEX(2)

Error: feature of qualified call is not available to client class.
What to do: make sure feature after dot is exported to caller.
```

I hope somebody can help me with this, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects are created with a creation instruction, so in your example you need to add a keyword `create` in front of `lista.make` to indicate that this is not a plain feature call:

```
create lista.make
```